# Cannot show images after fetching from an API

Tags: reactjs, request, axios, fetch, chain

I'm trying to chain two fetch request using axios. My code is :

```
const fetchCatsData = async  () => {
  
  const fetchBreeds = await axios.get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds", {
    headers: {
      "x-api-key": "MY API KEY ",
    },
  })
  await fetchBreeds.data.map(breed => {
    axios.get(`https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_ids=${breed.id}&include_breeds=false`)
    .then(res => breed.image_url = res.data[0].url)
  })
 
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_BREEDS, payload:  fetchBreeds.data })
```

It succeeds and in react dev tools , i see a special key called 'image_url'inside my context , with the url of the image.I click on it's value and it open the requested image.

But when i'm trying to show the image in an image HTML tag , it  shows nothing ...

Am i missing something ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the code here, i guess you are trying to wait until the image_url is set for all items in fetchBreeds.data. But it won't work in that way.

```
await fetchBreeds.data.map(breed => {
    axios.get(`https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_ids=${breed.id}&include_breeds=false`)
    .then(res => breed.image_url = res.data[0].url)
  })
```

You use `await` on the map function. The map function is not async, so when you dispatch the action, the image_urls are not set yet. When you checked the store and found the image_url was there is because the fetchBreeds.data was mutated by axios call directly without using redux dispatch system. This didn't trigger the UI re-render so image didn't show. What happened is shown below:

1. `dispatch({ type: FETCH_BREEDS, payload:  fetchBreeds.data })` This happens first.
2. Component is notified so re-render. image_url is not set yet, so image is empty
3. `.then(res => breed.image_url = res.data[0].url)` This is called next. Because the function holds the reference of the fetchBreeds.data, so it changes the fetchBreeds.data object directly without using reducer.
4. UI is not notified so it doesn't know image_url is changed and won't re-render.

I suggest you change the function to:

```
  await Promise.All(fetchBreeds.data.map(breed => {
    return axios.get(`https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_ids=${breed.id}&include_breeds=false`)
    .then(res => breed.image_url = res.data[0].url)
  }))
```